# How to extract a substring using this regex pattern? It's give a ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)

Tags: python, python-re

```py
import re, random, os, datetime, time
from os import remove
from unicodedata import normalize
from glob import glob


def learn_in_real_time(input_text, text):

    #Quita acentos y demas diacríticos excepto la ñ
    input_text = re.sub(
        r"([^n\u0300-\u036f]|n(?!\u0303(?![\u0300-\u036f])))[\u0300-\u036f]+", r"\1",
        normalize("NFD", input_text), 0, re.I
    )

    input_text = normalize( 'NFC', input_text) # -> NFC
    input_text_to_check = input_text.lower() #Convierte a minuscula todo

    words = []
    words_associations = []

    regex_what_who = r"(.*)\¿?(que sabes|que sabias|que sabrias|que te referis|que te refieres|que te referias|que te habias referido|que habias referido|a que|que|quienes|quien)\s*(con que|con lo que|con la que|con|acerca de que|acerca de quienes|acerca de quien|sobre de que|sobre que|sobre de quienes|sobre quienes|sobre de quien|sobre quien|)\s*(son|sean|es|serian|seria)\s*(iguales|igual|similares|similar|parecidos|parecido|comparables|comparable|asociables|asociable|distinguibles|distinguible|distintos|distinto|diferentes|diferente|diferenciables|diferenciable|)\s*(a |del |de |)\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)?"

    l = re.search(regex_what_who, input_text_to_check, re.IGNORECASE) #Con esto valido la regex haber si entra o no en el bloque de code

    if l:
        #print("C")
        association, = l.groups()
        association = association.strip()
        association_check = association + "\n" #Uso estas para las comparaciones, ya que sino las consideraria erroneamente como palabras que no estan en la lista solo por no tener el \n


        return text


    return text
```

I need it to extract the word that is in ((?: \ W + \ s *) +) and save it to a variable as a string, but the problem is that it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "answer_about_learned_in_txt.py", line 106, in <module>
    print(learn_in_real_time(input_t, text))
  File "answer_about_learned_in_txt.py", line 72, in learn_in_real_time
    association, = l.groups()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

How do I extract all what is in ((?: \ W + \ s *) +), and save it in a variable?

Taking advantage now that I ask how I would do to:

a) to extract everything that is in ((?: \ W + \ s *) +) and if there are blank spaces that it does not cut and save everything, for example: "Hello, how are you?"

b) to extract everything that is in ((?: \ W + \ s *) +) but to save up to the first white space, for example: "Hello"

---

I have the problem that if I put the following, position 6 of the tuple does not catch me

```py
if l:
        #print("C")
        #association, = l.groups()
        print(l.groups())
        association, _temp = l.group(6)
```

And it gives me this error

```
File "answer_about_learned_in_txt.py", line 74, in learn_in_real_time
    association, _temp = l.group(6)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
In the end I was able to solve it with the following
```

If you enter

> Que son los cometas

```py
print (l.groups ())
```

> ('', 'que', '', 'son', '', '', 'los cometas')

I'm interested in the seventh position of the tuple, counting from 1

```py
association = l.group (7)
```

And this give me :

> 'los cometas'

Comment: your search pattern have a lot of `OR`. write more correct patterns. do you need help? I think you're a copy-paste reg-ex from web.

Comment: @dzNET YES, I really need help, I don't know why this error is giving me I tried with groups () and with group (), but it keeps failing me. This is my code and needs some improvements but leaving the number of OR statements aside, I was having problem when i extracting the substring

Comment: let's back to the beginning. which word/text do you need to find? sorry I don't familiar with ES language.

Comment: at the end of the regex pattern, there is an instruction ((?:\w+\s*)+)?  What I wanted is to save whatever is in the place of that instruction in the variable called association

Comment: what do you know about ...   , what we need is the words that would be in those ...

Comment: this instruction doesn't work.

Comment: so, I want to know what words do you search. and I will update pattern string.

Comment: for example I need it to be able to extract the topic it is talking about, for example, if you tell it "What do you know about airplanes", the program must extract "airplanes".
Another example, "What do you know about flowers", the program should extract "flowers"

Comment: *"who eat earth"  
"what do you do what"  
"read stackoverflow about regexp"*  

**earth, what, regexp**  
  
  
correct? we are ignore context and collect last words of text?  
and the same in case ***"what do you know about about"***

Comment: the objective is that it only extracts the word if and only if the previous context matches. For this I put the if condition

Comment: in this case we care about the phrase that follows the entire regex pattern. For example
"What do you know about red flowers", the program should extract "red flowers"

Comment: error below happened in no results case.

Comment: add validation statement `if res.groups().__len__().__gt__(0): do_staff()`

Comment: I recommended to do not use method `.groups()` or check documentation about additional parameters / flags to correct function behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238449/discussion-between-dznet-and-electrisik-vocal).

Comment: you are right to send an empty one, for example "Que son", it remains ('', 'Que', '', 'son', '', '', None '), and this give me a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: You suggest placing this second validation statement `if res.groups().__len__().__gt__(0): do_staff()` just before than the asignation `association = l.group (7)`  ?

Comment: yes. `do_staff` - is your code to execute.  BUT why are you using `.groups()`? keep it simple s.. =)

Comment: I corrected the s before, however with that condition the error if you do not enter anything happens the same, but with a try-except statement I could solve it somehow.

Comment: Really thanks for the help, but with the `if res.groups().__len__().__gt__(0): ` i couldn't solve it, the only option that i found is use the exceptions when the users doesn't enter a word in the last

Comment: enjoy! and welcome. I'll update topic if I'll found solution. have a nice coding.

Comment: Really thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's update patterns string to a logical view and follow main feature.

```
regex_what_who = r"(que sabes|que sabias|que sabrias|que te referis|que te refieres|que te referias|que te habias referido|que habias referido|a que|que|quienes|quien|con que|con lo que|con la que|con|acerca de que|acerca de quienes|acerca de quien|sobre de que|sobre que|sobre de quienes|sobre quienes|sobre de quien|sobre quien|son|sean|es|serian|seria|iguales|igual|similares|similar|parecidos|parecido|comparables|comparable|asociables|asociable|distinguibles|distinguible|distintos|distinto|diferentes|diferente|diferenciables|diferenciable).*(a|del|de)\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)?"
```

then, fix error first error in case if we got one result or many:

```
association, _temp = l.groups()
```

It Work's! -)
[image: it work's!]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help the reason why it failed was that I was using group () but with wrong tuple position parameter. By the way, do you know how to make the last word only extract up to the first blank space found?
For example, "Que son los cometas azules" and the program extract only "cometas" and not "cometas azules"